# Translation for "comment edited" in revisions not used

Tags: bug, status-review, revisions-list, localization, edit-summary

When moderator makes an edit of description for post edit there's additional part in [revisions page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/12696/revisions) for that revision:

> [image]

[String is translated](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/7884) in Traducir, but for some reason not used.

Comment: Looks like an identical string elsewhere in the code is marked as translatable, but this instance (in the revision history) isn't.

Comment: @V2Blast there're many such places found, and I think much more not found yet :)